# linq join on null

Tags: linq

What's the difference between a Single and a SingleOrDefault ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is how they treat an empty sequence.

- [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx) throws an exception if there are no element is found.
- [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) returns the value `default(T)` if no element is found. For reference types and nullables the default value is null. For non-nullable value types it is 0 or similar.

The [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) and [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) methods are also related. Here are all four in a table:

```
method           no records  multiple records
---------------------------------------------
Single           exception   exception       
SingleOrDefault  default(T)  exception       
First            exception   first record    
FirstOrDefault   default(T)  first record
```

All these methods also have an overload that takes a predicate.

Another related method is [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) which allows you to specify what the default value should be if the sequence is empty, rather than just using the default value for the type.

Comment: `SingleOrDefault` returns `default(T)` which might be `null`, but for e.g. `int` it will be `0`

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Mmmm, yeah! I wish I had an excuse like "I just woke up" or something, but can't think of one right now. ;-) Thanks!

Comment: Eh, we're all guilty of that...I just never know when its appropriate to edit another persons post if the omission is "obvious".

Answer (score 3):

Single:

> Returns the only element of a sequence that satisfies a specified condition, and throws an exception if more than one such element exists.

Single or Default:

> Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty; this method throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.

So you can use SingleOrDefault to populate a property/column with a default value if you don't want that property/column to accept NULLs.

Answer (score 1):

Single will throw an Exception if there is anything other than a single result for the query.

SingleOrDefault will only throw an Exception if there are more than one results to your query. If there are no results, you will get back a default value (which is typically `null`).

Answer (score 1):

also it's kinda analagous to an outer join in SQL when used in a Linq join.

Answer (score 0):

Single throws a exception if there is more then one result.  SingleOrDefault (I am assuming you meant SingleOrDefault not SingleifDefault) will return null if there is more then one result.